# How does the Rust compiler make sense of log_u32 and log_many in the wasm-bindgen example below?

Tags: c, rust, interop, extern, wasm-bindgen

The following code is taken from the `wasm-bindgen` [tutorial](https://rustwasm.github.io/docs/wasm-bindgen/examples/console-log.html).

My question pertains to the code block that begins with
`extern "C"` and contains the functions `log_u32` and `log_many`.

From what I understand, calling `extern "C"` lets you use C functions in Rust. For example, `log` here is simply the `log` function from C, if I understand correctly.

But, here's my issue: That code block also contains the functions `log_u32` and `log_many`. But there are no C functions named `log_u32` and `log_many` that I'm aware of. So where do these two functions get their definitions? How does the Rust compiler make sense of them?

```
#![allow(unused_variables)]
fn main() {
use wasm_bindgen::prelude::*;

#[wasm_bindgen(start)]
pub fn run() {
    bare_bones();
    using_a_macro();
    using_web_sys();
}

// First up let's take a look of binding `console.log` manually, without the
// help of `web_sys`. Here we're writing the `#[wasm_bindgen]` annotations
// manually ourselves, and the correctness of our program relies on the
// correctness of these annotations!

#[wasm_bindgen]
extern "C" {
    // Use `js_namespace` here to bind `console.log(..)` instead of just
    // `log(..)`
    #[wasm_bindgen(js_namespace = console)]
    fn log(s: &str);

    // The `console.log` is quite polymorphic, so we can bind it with multiple
    // signatures. Note that we need to use `js_name` to ensure we always call
    // `log` in JS.
    #[wasm_bindgen(js_namespace = console, js_name = log)]
    fn log_u32(a: u32);

    // Multiple arguments too!
    #[wasm_bindgen(js_namespace = console, js_name = log)]
    fn log_many(a: &str, b: &str);
}

fn bare_bones() {
    log("Hello from Rust!");
    log_u32(42);
    log_many("Logging", "many values!");
}

// Next let's define a macro that's like `println!`, only it works for
// `console.log`. Note that `println!` doesn't actually work on the wasm target
// because the standard library currently just eats all output. To get
// `println!`-like behavior in your app you'll likely want a macro like this.

macro_rules! console_log {
    // Note that this is using the `log` function imported above during
    // `bare_bones`
    ($($t:tt)*) => (log(&format_args!($($t)*).to_string()))
}

fn using_a_macro() {
    console_log!("Hello {}!", "world");
    console_log!("Let's print some numbers...");
    console_log!("1 + 3 = {}", 1 + 3);
}

// And finally, we don't even have to define the `log` function ourselves! The
// `web_sys` crate already has it defined for us.

fn using_web_sys() {
    use web_sys::console;

    console::log_1(&"Hello using web-sys".into());

    let js: JsValue = 4.into();
    console::log_2(&"Logging arbitrary values looks like".into(), &js);
}

}
```

Comment: In `wasm_bindgen` `extern` denotes a js function, not a C function.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman So the `"C"` part of `extern "C"` here is just an irrelevant artifact?

Comment: It's because in the language `extern "X"` denotes a C function, but `wasm_bindgen`'s macro transform that into something else.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Would it still work if we omit the `"C"`, and typed `extern [...]` instead of `extern "C" [...]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really simple, you tell it what function to use with `js_name = log` it uses the `log` function.

In JavaScript that function is polymorphic and can handle different types of input, since there are no polymorphic functions in Rust to satisfy the compiler whe have to give different names to the different overloaded versions of `log`.